# How should I store salts and passwords in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to store passwords and salts in MongoDB and I'm not sure which datatype should be used.  When I use strings, the encrypted password appears to be stored correctly, but the generated salt, which is created with `new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');`, seems to have characters that weren't recognized.  For example, I have a salt stored as �y_�6j(�l~Z}0ۡ\" and I don't think this is correct.

Is the problem that it's stored as a string?

Comment: are you using mongodb with nodejs? If yes then there is a NPM package -
 [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), available for this purpose. You can match passwords without saving the salts.

Comment: I am using nodejs.  If each user has a different salt and the salt isn't stored anywhere, how will it know what salt to use when hashing the password to compare to the stored hashed password?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While registering a user, you can generate a hashed password using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt). Let's call this password as `P#1`. Save this hashed password (`P#1`) in your database **only**, and not the salt.

While logging in a user, generate hashed version of the password which the user sends, let's call it `P#2`. Now you just have to match `P#` and `P#2`. If they match, the user is authenticated. This way you can perform authentication without actually saving the salt in your database.

I will try to put it in simple way with the help of an example.

```js
// My user schema

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

// hash the password
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};
var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

```js
// My APIs for registering and authenticating a user

var User = require('/path/to/user/model');

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var new_user = new User({
    username: req.body.username
  });

  new_user.password = new_user.generateHash(req.body.password);
  new_user.save();
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {

    if (!user.validPassword(req.body.password)) {
      //password did not match
    } else {
      // password matched. proceed forward
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: what is userInfo?

Answer (score 4):

Ankit Gomkale's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094720/7365866) is correct (and IMHO clean!), but you might wonder how it's possible to **verify the hashed password is the same as the input string being tested**.

This is because the output of `bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);` is not a "hashed password", it is a "hash string", of the form ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)):

```
$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy
\__/\/ \____________________/\_____________________________/
Alg Cost      Salt                        Hash
```

Therefore, this string contains the password hash, but also the salt. Verification of a password (e.g. in `bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);`) will use this salt, not create a new random salt.